# Can't create Performance point data source at subsite level

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, performancepoint, business-intelligence

I cannot create PPS data source(DS) at sub-site level.

For example : 
when I am creating DS at site : https://mysp.a.b
then everything works.

When I am trying to create DS at subsite :  https://mysp.a.b/mysubite
then I am getting following error : 
"An unexpected system error has occurred. Additional details have been logged for your administrator."

I tried to add permissions to web application.

```
$w = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity https://mysp.a.b 
$w.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity("Domain\PPS_Account")
```

It did not help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question, maybe it will help somebody.

So what I did.

1) I opened dashboard designer from root site level( https://mysp.a.b ).
2) Next in tab Home, I added the new list and pick up the DataSource list from my sub-site( https://mysp.a.b/mysubite) and I was able to create a new data source within this list.

I did the same for Dashboards/Report/Filter in this sub-site.
Hope this will some others.